# Get Step Sensor Data in background and store in SharedPreference/SQLite

Tags: java, android, background, sensors

I have tried many ways to get sensor data in background and store the value into shared preference or SQLite, but none of them work. I think it is because of the Android Oreo Background restriction stuff.

I have tried

- Alarm Manager with Broadcast Receiver
- Alarm Manager with Service

and now I'm using the WorkManager. Not really working either. What am I doing wrong? Is it impossible to get sensor data in background now? Is there any other alternative way?

> MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    localDatabaseHelper = new LocalDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TEST STORAGE", MODE_PRIVATE);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    stepSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

    WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).cancelAllWorkByTag("Update-Shared-Preference");
    WorkRequest updateSharedPreference = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UpdateStepWork.class)
            .addTag("Update-Shared-Preference")
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueue(updateSharedPreference);
}
```

> Work

```
public class UpdateStepWork extends Worker implements SensorEventListener {

private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor stepSensor;
private LocalDatabaseHelper localDatabase;

public UpdateStepWork(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    Log.i("WORK", "STARTED");
    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TEST STORAGE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    stepSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    localDatabase = new LocalDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).cancelAllWorkByTag("Update-Shared-Preference");
    WorkRequest updateSharedPreference = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UpdateStepWork.class)
            .setInitialDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addTag("Update-Shared-Preference")
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueue(updateSharedPreference);

    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, stepSensor);
    if(sensorManager.registerListener(this, stepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)){
        return Worker.Result.success();
    }else
        return Worker.Result.failure();
}



@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    int steps = (int) event.values[0];

    Log.i("Steps from sensor", steps + "");

    if(sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("steps", steps).commit()){
        Log.i("Shared Preference", "SUCCESS STORED: " + steps);

        if(localDatabase.updateDailyData(steps)){
            Log.i("LOCAL DATABASE", "SUCCESS AT " + getCurrentTimeStamp());
            Cursor data = localDatabase.getData();

            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                Log.i("DATA", data.getString(0) + "    " + data.getInt(1));
            }
        }

    }else{
        Log.i("Shared Preference", "FAILED STORED: " + steps);
    }
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, stepSensor);
    sensorManager = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical approach to collect sensor data in the background is using a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services).

SharedPreferences are not an ideal way to store sensor data. I recommend that you store the sensor data in a .csv file or a database.

Comment: Anyone knows how googleFit track steps in background?